# Concatenation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, concatenation, string-concatenation

My code is like below.

```
<a class="page-link{{ $notification_link['active'] ? 'blue' : '' }}"  {{ $notification_link['url'] == null ? '' : (href="'.route('notification',substr($notification_link['url'], -1)).'") }}>some text</a>
```

I am getting error like below

```
syntax error, unexpected '='
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing a quotation mark:

```
<a class="page-link{{ $notification_link['active'] ? 'blue' : '' }}"  {{ $notification_link['url'] == null ? '' : ('href="'.route('notification',substr($notification_link['url'], -1))) }}>some text</a>
```